# Is it possible to have this div expand as its content expands?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

The difficult issue is that I need this CSS rule: `html {height: 100%}` in order to make my first page work. See [prototype](https://infinite-ridge-55397.herokuapp.com/).

This allows the login `div` to be centered based on the height of the window.

[image]

However, the second page now is stuck at this height and does not expand as I populate the content using ajax.  Either click on the star [in this link](https://infinite-ridge-55397.herokuapp.com/) or see below.

You can see where the dotted line stops is the original rendering of the window at 100%.

If I remove the height of 100% it will expand but then the SignOn page is broken as it has no height.

Note: React is controlling the changing from page to the other using a simple conditional in the JSX based on the application state.

Should I alter the CSS height for HTML based on application state or is there a better way to do this?

A better question, might be, that after the content in the div changes, shouldn't the div expand to reflect this?

[image: Second Page]

**Relevant CSS**

```
html{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  background-image: url('_images/bg_paper.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#app{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#contents{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#top-1{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-top: 3px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#top-2{
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 1px dotted #888888;
  border-right: 1px dotted #888888;
}
#container-1{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 44px;
}
#container-2{
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 1px dotted #888888;
  border-right: 1px dotted #888888;
}
.body{
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: use `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%`. Also, remove those tags from `html` and only use them in `body`.

Comment: Remove `width` and `height` from `html`? and add a `min-height` to `body` set at 100%.  What is the reasoning?

Comment: I tried that, it does not work.

Comment: Make a special class for the sign-on so it's positioned accordingly and remove the height.

Answer (score 3):

I think using `flex` is much easier to deal with this kind of situations.
You can set your main container as `flex` and play with the `justify` and `align` properties to center the elements.
The problem here is that you got a fixed positioned element as a toolbar that goes out of flow, so we will set `margin-top` to the next element respectively to the fixed element's height.
another issue is that you want to center the login component when its parent isn't at the same height as the view port, this can be handled with a `min-height:100vh` to the main container.

Here is a very basic demonstration of the above:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      login: true,
      items: [
        'item 1',
        'item 2',
        'item 3',
        'item 4',
      ]
    };
  }

  addITem = e => {
    const { items } = this.state;
    const nextItem = `item ${items.length + 2}`;
    this.setState({ items: [...items, nextItem] });
  }

  loginView = e => {
    this.setState({ login: true });
  }

  login = e => {
    this.setState({ login: false });
  }

  render() {
    const { items, login } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="toolbar">
          <div className="title">This is a fixed toolbar, click to add items</div>
          <button className="btn" onClick={this.addITem}>+</button>
          <button className="btn" onClick={this.loginView}>Login</button>
        </div>
        {login ?
          <div className="login-wrapper">
            <div className="login">
              <label>Login</label>
              <input placeHolder="user name" />
              <input type="password" placeHolder="password" />
              <button className="btn" onClick={this.login}>Go</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          :
          <div className="items">
            {items.map(item => <div className="item">{item}</div>)}
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.toolbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

.title {
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 65px;
  align-content: baseline;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #333;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.login-wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}

.login {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting.  I'll look into flex more.  But according to your last post, the containing div should expand.